# no data in asp table after Post back

Tags: vb.net

I have updatePanel, in which I am having tables as shown

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DynCreated" EnableViewState="true" UpdateMode="Conditional"
            runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate >
                <div style="display: none" enableviewstate="true"> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="flgClear" EnableViewState="true" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="flgAdd" EnableViewState="true" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtList" EnableViewState="true" Text="|" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDelete" EnableViewState="true" Text="|" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
         <asp:Table ID="tblGrid" CssClass="grid" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0"
                    Width="100%" EnableViewState="true" runat="server">   <asp:TableRow TableSection="TableHeader" ID="trHeader" CssClass="crid-header Datagrid-header"
                        runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="hdrSequence" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSequence" Text="#" CssClass="cel" runat="server" />
                        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="hdrHouseBill" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblHouseBill" Text="HouseBill" CssClass="ceva-form-label" runat="server" />
                        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="hdrFileNumber" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFileNumber" Text="FileNumbere" CssClass="ceva-form-label" runat="server" />
                        </asp:TableHeaderCell>

                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="text-center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewHB" CssClass="tn btn-dialog" Text="Add New Status"

                    OnClientClick="return ShowNewLeg();" runat="server" />

                    <asp:Button  Text="Validate" CssClass="cen btn-dialog" runat="server" ID="btnValidate"   />


                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="tn-dialog" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return Save()" Visible="false"
                        runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CssClass=" btn-dialog" OnClientClick="window.returnValue = 1; window.close(); return false;"
                        Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" CssClass=tn btn-dialog" Text="Clear All" OnClientClick="return ClearTable();"
                        runat="server" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hndtimeformat" runat="server" name="hndtimeformat" value="0"
                        style="display: none" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

From the back-end i am adding new Row to the tblGrid

```
     For j As Integer = tblGrid.Rows.Count To maxRow
      Dim newRow As TableRow= New TableRow()
     newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewLabel(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "SEQ", 
     tblGrid.Rows.Count, tblGrid.Rows.Count, "40px", bColor))
     newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewText(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "HB", "", 
      tblGrid.Rows.Count, "10px", "", 3, "none", False))
     newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewLabel(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "FN", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, "60px", ""))
   newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewDD(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "ST", statusup, tblGrid.Rows.Count, "10px", "", 3, "none", True))
 newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewDT(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "datetime", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, ""))
   newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewAC(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "LC", "", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, "0.0", AutoCompletor.DisplayFieldType.Code, "", "", False))
 newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewText(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "SG", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, "10px", "", 0, "none"))
 newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewCB(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "CB", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, "5px", bColor))
  newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewText(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "Note", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, "10px", "", 0, "none"))
 newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewLabel(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "Er", "", tblGrid.Rows.Count, "40px", bColor))
newRow.Cells.Add(CreateNewImage(tblGrid.Rows.Count, "btn", tblGrid.Rows.Count))  tblGrid.Rows.Add(newRow)   Next j
```

I am getting data what ever  i have before post back, after post back its not having any data which is present in the tabGrid.

Do I need to use ViewState or Session?  is there any way i get the data?
Please advice !!

Answer (score 0):

Put your data into a viewstate and get them after postback

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewState variable if you need to use this data only during navigation inside this page. If you want keep alive data for the entire session  better to use a Session variable, so you will not loose these rows also  if you go in other pages.

Asp:Table isn't the right element to use if you want manage data, i suggest to try this solution (is only an example):

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="tblGrid" CssClass="grid"  CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                <Columns >
                   <asp:TemplateField >
                        <HeaderTemplate >
                             <asp:Label ID="lblSequence" Text="#" CssClass="cel" runat="server" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSequenceItem" Text="<%# Eval("col1")  %>" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                             <asp:Label ID="lblHouseBill" Text="HouseBill" CssClass="ceva-form-label" runat="server" />
                   </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblHouseBillItem" Text="<%# Eval("col2")  %>" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                             <asp:Label ID="lblFileNumber" Text="FileNumbere" CssClass="ceva-form-label" runat="server" />
                   </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFileNumberItem" Text="<%# Eval("col3")  %>" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

and this for runtime data binding:
Creation of datatable

```
   Dim dt As New Data.DataTable("rows")
    Dim col1 As New Data.DataColumn("col1", GetType(String))
    Dim col2 As New Data.DataColumn("col2", GetType(Integer))
    Dim col3 As New Data.DataColumn("col3", GetType(String))

    dt.Columns.Add(col1)
    dt.Columns.Add(col2)
    dt.Columns.Add(col3)

    dt.Rows.Add ("test",1,"test") 'statement for row insert

    ViewState("datasource") = dt

    tblGrid.DataSource = dt
    tblGrid.DataBind()
```

And binding in postback:

```
   Dim dt As New Data.DataTable("rows")

    If Not ViewState("datasource") Is Nothing Then dt = ViewState("datasource")

    tblGrid.DataSource = dt
    tblGrid.DataBind()
```

Comment: if i put in ViewState its give me "Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable." error

Comment: Try to use define a datatable instead a table, in this way you can save in viewstate and also set like table.datasource